Relative Dolbeault cohomology using currents
I need to compute the cohomology groups of some relative holomorphic $i$-forms $H^\bullet(X, \Omega^i_{X/Y})$ for a fibration of complex manifolds $X\to Y$, using a kind of distributional de Rham complex of relative currents
$$
\Omega^i_{X/Y} \to \mathcal{D}^{i,0}_{X/Y} \xrightarrow{\overline{\partial}} \mathcal{D}^{i,1}_{X/Y}  \xrightarrow{\overline{\partial}} \ldots
$$
Does anyone have a reference where all the properties you'd need/expect from this construction are written down?
